# How to build .csproj with C# 7 code from command line (msbuild)

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I use some C# 7 features in my project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}

public byte ContainerVersion
{
    get => 1;
    private set => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and it builds fine in visual studio 2017, but I get an error on my CI agent when using old msbuild (`v14.0 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuid.exe consoleApplication.csproj.`):

`error CS1513: } expected`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'll need to install `msbuild-2015` on your CI agent.

https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

The default install directory for msbuild will be:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: MSBuild 15 is installed with VS.  It would be under %VSINSTALLDIR%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.  The Build Tools SKU is intended for CI agents where you don't want to have VS installed.  It's worth noting both cases.

Comment: Jimmy, you are right. But, we have some special tasks that uses `msbuild` manual on CI agents.

Comment: Even after installing the standalone 2017 build tools on a server c:\program files (x86)\msbuild\15.0 has nothing in it but a \FileTracker folder there is no msbuild.exe or anything. I did have VS2017 installed on the server before I tried this but seems like something is messed up, any ideas?

Comment: Do you know, why the `msbuild.exe` which comes with .NET Framework is unable build C# 7 features?

Answer (score 5):

Having installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, the path to msbuild.exe on my machine is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`